# Javascript to add offset (-4 or -5 daylight saving time) to date YYYY-MM-DD formatted string

Tags: javascript, date, datetimeoffset

I am pretty new to Javascript, I have a requirement where I'll get a Date as one of the input value in format YYYY-MM-DD (Eg: 2014-07-01), and I need to convert this to UTC offset (-4 or -5) based on daylight saving time (Eg: 2014-07-01T00:00:00-04:00". I am using below piece of code, but it's not adding the offset value at the end of the date string instead I am getting like this "2014-07-01T00:00:00.000Z".

```
            if (wheelRequest.RegEndDate){
                var regEndDate = new Date(wheelRequest.RegEndDate);
                var regEndDateFormatted = new Date(regEndDate).toISOString();
                licensenumObj.enddate    =    regEndDateFormatted ;
            }
```

I've verified the other post ([How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)) but it doesn't mention how to show the offset value at the end.
Please advise on how I can able to add the offset based on my need.

Thanks,
Suman.

Comment: Some ideas [here](https://usefulangle.com/post/30/javascript-get-date-time-with-offset-hours-minutes). FYI `regEndDate` is already a `Date` object. No need for `new Date(regEndDate)`.

Comment: Note that dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD are parsed as UTC, If you simply want to add a time of 00:00:00 with the host timezone offset, then convert the local offset (returned in minutes by [*getTImezoneOffset*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)) to HH:mm format, taking care to reverse the sign, and append the time and offset to the string.

Comment: You can also add the offset using the *timeZone* option with [*Intl.DateTimeFormat.formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) to get the offset as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/257182).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to work with [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/), [where to use it](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/)

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

const input = '2020-11-11';

const time = moment(input);
time.format();
```

output: `Wed Nov 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0300`

changing timezone

```
const time = moment.tz(input, 'Asia/Tokyo');
time.format();
```

output: `Wed Nov 11 2020 12:00:00 GMT+0900`

Comment: Hi Patrick, here my requirement is to get the date from "2014-07-01"  to like this "2014-07-01T00:00:00-04:00" , where the offset will be at the end. please advise.

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking you need to see this:

```js
function specialTime(dateString){
  let dt = new Date(dateString), os = dt.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
  if(os < 0 && os > -10){
    os = '+0'+Math.abs(os);
  }
  else if(os < 10){
    os = '-0'+os;
  }
  else{
    os = '-'+os;
  }
  return dt.toISOString().replace(/\..+$/, os+':00');
}
console.log(specialTime('2014-07-01'));
```

Comment: Hi StackSlave, when running this I am still getting similar to what I am currently ("2014-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"), here my need was to get the date like this "2014-07-01T00:00:00-04:00" where the offset will be at the end. Any tweaks to get like this way?, please assist.

Comment: Looks like this should work for me @StackSlave, thanks much, will try to incorporate in my code.